# count with group on eloquent laravel

Tags: oracle, laravel, eloquent

Hi i have make this query on oracle:

```
select count(*), queue
from cases
where queue not in ('OPBO_SA_Work-in-Prog','OP_AD_WIN_TECH')
group by queue
```

this is the result:

```
18  OP_AD_WIN_ACTIVATION
18  OP_AD_WIN_HARDWARE
4   OP_AD_WIN_FIBER
37  OPBO_WIN_Fiber_pend_i
8   OP_AD_WIN_RELOCATION
47  OPBO_WIN_Act_pend_i
```

i wana make the same on laravel i try this:

```
  'total' => $this->cases->select('queue')->whereNotIn('queue',
['OPBO_SA_Work-in-Prog','OP_AD_WIN_TECH'])->groupBy('queue')->count(),
```

the result is
18 ( only the first number )

Comment: Remove the count()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get() instead of count():

```
$cases = \DB::table('cases')
    ->select(\DB::raw('count(*) as queue_count, queue'))
    ->whereNotIn('queue', ['OPBO_SA_Work-in-Prog','OP_AD_WIN_TECH'])
    ->groupBy('queue')
    ->get();
```

Comment: ok i made it now the result is the queues ( all ) without numbers

Comment: then: select count(*) as cnt, queue

Comment: $users = \DB::table('cases')
                     ->select(\DB::raw('count(*) as queue_count, queue'))
                     ->whereNotIn('queue',
['OPBO_SA_Work-in-Prog','OP_AD_WIN_TECH'])->groupBy('queue')
                     ->get();